# .Net 5+ way of creating a platform agnostic RSA key pair

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to write a C# version of exactly the following OpenSsl command:

openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048

I'd like it to be platform agnostic and work equally well in Windows, Linux and Mac.

So far I have:

```
using (var rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
{
    var keyParameters = rsa.ExportParameters();

    // Not sure how to get the key in bytes
    var bytes = GetBytes(keyParameters);
    
    // Encrypt the bytes here
    var encryptedKey = Encrypt(bytes);

    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, encryptedKey);
}
```

Not sure how to write the `GetBytes` piece, or if you can suggest a better approach.

Comment: If you want to export the keypair you must choose a format, there is more than one. I think `RSA.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` for public keys and `RSA.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()` for private keys are the best choices for maximum portability. Ultimately your choice here needs to be guided by what *other* software/platforms your exported keys need to be consumed by. In particular, older .Net versions don't support these formats.

Comment: @malik-masis: Please stop adding the .net tag to .net-core questions. The first sentence of the tag description states: "Do NOT use for questions about .NET Core"